# Select and copy table to clipboard

Tags: javascript, html, html-table, copy, paste

I want to select table without headers, and it works, but I cannot get it so, that it would copy to clipboard.

Here's the page: http://tuudik.lohv.eu/Asjad/EURXML/

Here's the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
    <title>ECB kursid seisuga: 2011-04-01 </title>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
<style type="text/css">
table
{
border-collapse:collapse;
}
table, td, th
{
border:1px solid black;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function selectElementContents(el) {
        var body = document.body, range, sel;
        if (body.createTextRange) {
            range = body.createTextRange();
            range.moveToElementText(el);
            range.select();
            range.execCommand('Copy');
        } else if (document.createRange && window.getSelection) {
            range = document.createRange();
            range.selectNodeContents(el);
            sel = window.getSelection();
            sel.removeAllRanges();
            sel.addRange(range);
            sel.execCommand('Copy');
        }

    }
</script>
</head>

<body>
<table cellpadding="2">
<thead>

    <tr>
        <th>Valuuta</th>
        <th>Kurss</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody id="currencies">
<tr><td>USD</td><td>1,4141</td></tr><tr><td>JPY</td><td>118,56</td></tr><tr><td>DKK</td><td>7,4564</td></tr><tr><td>GBP</td><td>0,88150</td></tr><tr><td>NOK</td><td>7,8055</td></tr><tr><td>RUB</td><td>40,1500</td></tr><tr><td>CAD</td><td>1,3686</td></tr></tbody>

</table>
<input type="button" value="select table"
   onclick="selectElementContents( document.getElementById('currencies') );">
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

This works for me on IE8:

```
    var table = document.getElementById('copyHtmlToClipboard');
    // Below line is essential !!!
    table.contentEditable = 'true';   

    var controlRange = document.body.createControlRange();
    controlRange.addElement(table);
    controlRange.execCommand("Copy");
```

Comment: `TypeError: document.body.createControlRange is not a function`

Comment: Also `table.contentEditable = 'true';` is invalid. you cannot pass a String

Answer (score 0):

In most browsers it isn't possible to copy to the system clipboard. To do this you need to use a hack. The most common way is to use Flash. [ZeroClipboard](http://code.google.com/p/zeroclipboard/) does this and appears to work quite well.

By the way, `execCommand()` is a method of `document` and `TextRange` objects, not `Selection` objects, so `sel.execCommand("Copy")` couldn't possibly work.

**UPDATE**

I've never actually used ZeroClipboard. Having looked at the docs, it doesn't look like it does what I had hoped (there seems to be no way to copy rich text) and is even more of a gruesome hack than I thought. You could copy the table's content as text via `innerHTML` using ZeroClipboard, but whether this is acceptable or not depends on what you're hoping the user can do with the copied content.

Comment: OK, I'll try this ZeroClipboard. I tried to make workaround on this javascript without having any great knowledge about it:)

Comment: I dont get it, how i select table with zeroclipboard?